# The following packages have unmet dependencies (apache)

Tags: package-management, apache2, dependencies

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

apache2: 
    Depends: apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1) but 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.2 is to be installed or
             apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed or
             apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed or
             apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1) but 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.2 is to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Having trouble reinstalling apache.

Answer (score 10):

First go back to a state there all dependencies are satisfied:

```
 sudo apt-get install -f
```

Try to remove all apache stuff:

```
 sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends "apache*"
```

Reinstall now all necessary dependencies:

```
 sudo apt-get install -f
```

Now you can give the apache installation a new try.
If the problem persists, please provide more informations.

Comment: When I tried using your commands I get the same message of unmet dependencies after **sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-mysql phpmyadmin  I then tried your command you provided with no result.>>** warning:** there's no installed package matching apache2.conf   Thanks.

Comment: 1st 'apt-get install -f' to go back to a stable situation

Comment: dpkg --purge --force-depends needs quotes around "apache*" because your invoked it in a directory containing files matching the "apache*" pattern (e.g. apache.conf)

Comment: @frqcuse If your problem is resolved, don't forget to close this question.

Comment: apt-get install -f worked better than apt-get -f install for me

Comment: Omg thanks so much....this was exactly what i needed